# X509CertificateHolder VerifyError

Tags: java, android, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Why is this very simple code throwing *java.lang.VerifyError* on Android? It works perfectly fine on desktop.

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
X509Certificate intermediateCa = loadCert();
new X509CertificateHolder(intermediateCa.getEncoded());
```

I tried different Android versions. If it makes any difference, this is the code I use to read the certificate (I tried also reading from PKCS12 KeyStore). I used the same certificate for tests on Android and desktop machines.

```
CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
InputStream is = mRes.openRawResource(R.raw.sign_cert);
X509Certificate intermediateCa = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(is);
is.close();
```

Comment: Can you add the complete stack trace. Is there a description of the exception as well?

Comment: There is no description. Stacktrace is pretty useless, there is only  java.lang.VerifyError: org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder on the top, next entry is my "new X509CertificateHolder" call.